# How do I change the collection value in firestore?(android java)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have set the document name automatically.

I want to change something in the document with no=9.

The 'no' is all different for each document.

If the document name exists
'firestore.collection("team_list").document("document_name").set(hashmap)'

But what should I do when the document name is automatic?

If when use rdbms, 'update field set city1='aa' where no=9 ;'

We will attach photos to help you understand.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glD6H.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know the document ID, have to do this in two steps:

1. First get the document ID/reference by running a query on the collection

```
firestore.collection("team_list").where('no', '==', '9').get();
```

2. Iterate over the documents & update the document using the document ID / reference.

Comment: How do I get the document ID value when I use get to get the information in that document?

Comment: the above query returns you the QuerySnapshot. To get each doc ref / ID, Iterate over the `documents` in that `QuerySnapshot`. like (in dart lang), snap.docs.forEach((doc) {
        print(doc.id);
      });